# How to get pathlib’s unix path handling goodies without the system specific ones, eg Path.resolve() changes /tmp to /private/tmp

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pathlib

Hit an interesting case with pathlib where I am using it to represent paths on a android device, not the machine the python is actively running on. Is it still possible to make use of pathlib’s sugary syntax and ability to resolve unix-wide truisms such as relative paths “../../“ without resolving device specific symlink things like “/tmp/path” -> “/private/tmp/path”?

For the most part, pathlib makes handling paths on the device super easy, but i run into problems when wanting to resolve a path on the device without using the host python machine’s symlink resolving mechanisms.

I love using pathlib instead of strings. Is it possible to do path manipulations and actions with the Path object but then send off the final file command to the device ssh’d into?

The only piece from resolve i’d like is the ability to turn (Path(“/tmp/analysis/ptool”) / “../../“).resolve take care of the .. but not change /tmp to /private/tmp, which is not a symlink on the device i’m about to use this path command with.

The example is a little trivial “just do it with strings”, but the organization and automation i want to apply this on is significantly cleaner and easier to read as Path objects instead of strings. If possible, it would be great to make it work.

```
In [1]: import pathlib

In [2]: from pathlib import Path

In [3]: Path('/tmp/hello').resolve()
Out[3]: PosixPath('/private/tmp/hello')
```

[image]

MacOS, Python3.7.3

Comment: Run `ls -ld /tmp` and look at its output.

Comment: Or run `cd /tmp; pwd -P` in bash.

Comment: ...why are you using `resolve()` if you don't want the thing it's documented to do?

Comment: Ah I was sure this was user error somehow. This makes sense. Thanks! Still, this breaks my use case. I will edit the wuestion to explain how.

Comment: BTW, generally speaking, editing a question in a way that invalidates existing answers is frowned on (in favor of asking a new/different question). That said, since there's now a good answer to the question-as-edited, I'm not asking you to do that now... but do consider it a note for the future.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I thought about which way to go, and in this case thought the old question was so bad it didn't really need to be asked in an "edited" format and would just lead to confusion, so I just asked what I meant to ask. Will just make a new question in the future as that's the best of both worlds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using a whole `Path` in this case seems wrong as it exposes methods like [`stat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.stat) which will try and operate on your local system, rather than the remote device.  using a [`PurePosixPath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePosixPath) looks better as it doesn't expose as much, and it's easy to add in a `resolve` method in a derived class:

```py
from pathlib import PurePosixPath

class ResolvingPosixPath(PurePosixPath):
    def resolve(self):
        if not self.is_absolute():
            raise ValueError('only able to resolve absolute paths')

        sep = self._flavour.sep
        path = ''

        for name in str(self).split(sep):
            if not name or name == '.':
                # current dir
                continue
            if name == '..':
                # parent dir
                path, _, _ = path.rpartition(sep)
                continue

            path = path + sep + name

        return path or sep
```

I've ripped the relevant code from [`pathlib._PosixFlavour.resolve`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/pathlib.py#L312), and 
you're obviously free to use shorter class names if that's convenient!

this can be used as you suggest you want:

```
hello = ResolvingPosixPath('/tmp') / 'hello'
print(hello.resolve())
```

giving me `'/tmp/hello'`

Answer (score 4):

`/private/tmp` is where `/tmp` contents are actually stored on Mac OS. On this platform, `/tmp` is a symlink. You can see this from the operating system, without using Python at all:

```
$ ls -l /tmp
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 11 Oct 22  2018 /tmp -> private/tmp
$ (cd /tmp && pwd -P)
/private/tmp
```

[`pathlib.Path.resolve()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve) replaces symlinks with the absolute paths they point to, so it's doing exactly what you're asking for.

See [Why is `/tmp` a symlink to `/private/tmp`?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/why-is-tmp-a-symlink-to-private-tmp) on our sister site [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).